# Merging the data of two columns of the same table into single column

Tags: java, sql

I have a single table and the sql query is returning 2 different columns. But I want the result of these two columns in one column and that too having unique results only.

You can also suggest anything if I can do something in Java code to get the desired result, i.e. after fetching the result(s) from the query, any Java code manipulation by which I can arrive at the solution to this problem.

I also don't want to append/ concatenate values of the two columns. 
I just want the result in one column with unique values only.

Example:

```
Column limitN    Column limitR
     3500            3500
     6500            6500
    10000            7500
    50000           50000
```

So in this case I want the required column values as:

```
     3500
     6500
     7500
    10000
    50000
```

Comment: Please show us code you've tried already, or the schema of your database. Otherwise it's a bit vague...

Comment: Sql server 2008
   table: LimitAmount
   columns: limitN,limitR,UserId,UserName   I want limitN and limitR column values in one and unique values only.

Comment: It's usually a good idea to include a sample of your data structure/code when asking a question. You're likely to get a much better response.

Comment: Which two columns did you want to join and what data types are they?

Comment: so do you want to join "123" to "456" and have "123-456" in a new column or have one row with "123" in one row and "456" in? It's not really clear. Sample data and expected results would help. Also, if it adds detail to your question, edit your question rather than adding comments.

Comment: @Tanner will u please suggest anything now..

Comment: @user2269302 suggestion provided below

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
SELECT  DISTINCT SingleValue
FROM    (
         SELECT  col1 + ' ' + col2 AS SingleValue
         FROM    YourTable
         )
```

The inner select concatenates your two columns together, the outer select gets just unique values. This concatenation assumes the values are varchar / string, otherwise you'd need to `CAST` them to varchars in order to concatenate

Comment: TBH I'm not sure it even needs the initial `col1, col2` - so just `SELECT DISTINCT col1 + ' ' + col2 AS SingleValue FROM YourTable`, but I think it's possibly easier to include additional logic in the more verbose approach I took.

Comment: CAST(col1 as varchar) + ' ' + CAST(col2 as varchar)

Comment: outer SingleValue won't work because it will be an invalid column name.

Comment: I also don't want to append/ concatenate values of the two columns.
I just want the result in one column with unique values only.   Example: limitN values:3500, 6500,10000,50000 limitR values:3500,6500,7500,50000 so in this case I want the required column values as: 3500,6500,7500,10000,50000

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `UNION` query to create a column with `DISTINCT` values in:

```
SELECT limitN AS limitJoined
FROM  YOUR_TABLE
UNION
SELECT  limitR AS limitJoined
FROM  YOUR_TABLE
```